# How can I select a password for a website with my keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, safari, password, keychain, shortcut

I store passwords for websites in my safari keychain and when I visit a website there is the key icon in the username field.  I can click on this key and autofill the username and password, but I hate touching my mouse.  Can I use a keyboard shortcut to click on that key icon?

Comment: This cannot be generalised for all websites. It depends on how the site was made. Can you provide an example to test with ? As a side note, pressing tab to move on to password field can sometimes bring up auto fill suggestion. Down arrow and enter.

Comment: https://www.chase.com is one example

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to have Safari AutoFill the credentials when you tick the **AutoFill user names and passwords** checkbox in the Preferences sheet below:

[image]

Comment: I already have that checked.  Safari autofills the password after I select an account when I click the key icon in the username field.

Comment: My experience is whether AutoFIll works depends on how the website has been programmed. Some websites auto-populate, others do not. I agree it'd be convenient if they all did as to both fields, but they don't.

Comment: Some websites may have a "remember me" feature which might try to fill in my username based on something in the session header like IP address etc. but that is not what I'm asking.  I'm asking if there's a hotkey for the key icon so I don't have to clicky click.